# Unit Testing with Complex Setup and Logic

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to become better at unit testing and one of my biggest uncertainties is writing unit tests for methods that require quite a bit of setup code, and I haven't found a good answer.  The answers that I find are generally along the lines of "break your tests down into smaller units of work" or "use mocks".  I'm trying to follow all of those best practices.  However, even with mocking (I'm using Moq) and trying to break down everything into the smallest unit of work, I eventually run into a method that has several inputs, makes calls to several mock services, and requires me to specify return values for those mock method calls.

Here's an example of the code under test:

```
public class Order
{
   public string CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
   public List<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
   public decimal Value { get { /* return the order's calculated value */ } }

   public Order()
   {
      this.Lines = new List<OrderLine>();
   }
}

public class OrderLine
{
   public string ItemId { get; set; }
   public int QuantityOrdered { get; set; }
   public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}

public class OrderManager
{
   private ICustomerService customerService;
   private IInventoryService inventoryService;

   public OrderManager(ICustomerService customerService, IInventoryService inventoryService)
   {
      // Guard clauses omitted to make example smaller
      this.customerService = customerService;
      this.inventoryService = inventoryService;
   }

   // This is the method being tested.  
   // Return false if this order's value is greater than the customer's credit limit.
   // Return false if there is insufficient inventory for any of the items on the order.
   // Return false if any of the items on the order on hold.
   public bool IsOrderShippable(Order order)
   {
      // Return false if the order's value is greater than the customer's credit limit
      decimal creditLimit = this.customerService.GetCreditLimit(order.CustomerId);
      if (creditLimit < order.Value)
      {
         return false;
      }

      // Return false if there is insufficient inventory for any of this order's items
      foreach (OrderLine orderLine in order.Lines)
      {
         if (orderLine.QuantityOrdered > this.inventoryService.GetInventoryQuantity(orderLine.ItemId)
         {
            return false;
         }
      }

      // Return false if any of the items on this order are on hold
      foreach (OrderLine orderLine in order.Lines)
      {
         if (this.inventoryService.IsItemOnHold(orderLine.ItemId))
         {
            return false;
         }
      }

      // If we are here, then the order is shippable
      return true;
   }
}
```

Here's a test:

```
[TestClass]
public class OrderManagerTests
{
   [TestMethod]
   public void IsOrderShippable_OrderIsShippable_ShouldReturnTrue()
   {
      // Setup inventory on-hand quantities for this test
      Mock<IInventoryService> inventoryService = new Mock<IInventoryService>();
      inventoryService.Setup(e => e.GetInventoryQuantity("ITEM-1")).Returns(10);
      inventoryService.Setup(e => e.GetInventoryQuantity("ITEM-2")).Returns(20);
      inventoryService.Setup(e => e.GetInventoryQuantity("ITEM-3")).Returns(30);

      // Configure each item to be not on hold
      inventoryService.Setup(e => e.IsItemOnHold("ITEM-1")).Returns(false);
      inventoryService.Setup(e => e.IsItemOnHold("ITEM-2")).Returns(false);
      inventoryService.Setup(e => e.IsItemOnHold("ITEM-3")).Returns(false);

      // Setup the customer's credit limit
      Mock<ICustomerService> customerService = new Mock<ICustomerService>();
      customerService.Setup(e => e.GetCreditLimit("CUSTOMER-1")).Returns(1000m);

      // Create the order being tested
      Order order = new Order { CustomerId = "CUSTOMER-1" };
      order.Lines.Add(new OrderLine { ItemId = "ITEM-1", QuantityOrdered = 10, UnitPrice = 1.00m });
      order.Lines.Add(new OrderLine { ItemId = "ITEM-2", QuantityOrdered = 20, UnitPrice = 2.00m });
      order.Lines.Add(new OrderLine { ItemId = "ITEM-3", QuantityOrdered = 30, UnitPrice = 3.00m });

      OrderManager orderManager = new OrderManager(
         customerService: customerService.Object,
         inventoryService: inventoryService.Object);
      bool isShippable = orderManager.IsOrderShippable(order);

      Assert.IsTrue(isShippable);
   }
}
```

This is an abbreviated example.  My actual methods that I'm testing are similar in their structure, but they often have a few more service methods that they're calling or they have more setup code for the models (for instance, the `Order` object requires more properties to be assigned in order for the test to work).

Given that some of my methods have to do several things at once like this example (such as methods that are behind button-click events), is this the best way of dealing with writing unit tests for those methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already on the right path. And at some point, if a 'method under test' is big (not complex), then your unit test is bound to be big (not complex). i tend to differentiate between code which is 'big' vs. code which is 'complex'. A complex code snippet needs to be simplified.. a big code snippet is sometimes more clearer yet simple..

In your case, your code is just big, not complex. Hence it is not a big deal, if your unit tests are big as well.

Having said that, here is how we can make it crisper and more readable.

Option #1

The target code under test seems to be:

public bool IsOrderShippable(Order order)

As i can see, there are at least 4 unit test scenarios straightaway:

```
   // Scenario 1: Return false if the order's value is 
   // greater than the customer's credit limit

   [TestMethod]
   public void IsOrderShippable_OrderValueGreaterThanCustomerCreditLimit_ShouldReturnFalse()
   {
      // Setup the customer's credit limit
      var customerService = new Mock<ICustomerService>();
      customerService.Setup(e => e.GetCreditLimit(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(1000m);

      // Create the order with value greater than credit limit
      var order = new Order { Value = 1001m };

      var orderManager = new OrderManager(
         customerService: customerService.Object,
         inventoryService: new Mock<IInventoryService>().Object);

      bool isShippable = orderManager.IsOrderShippable(order);

      Assert.IsFalse(isShippable);
   }
```

As you can see, this test is pretty compact. it doesn't bother to setup a lot of mocks etc. that you don't expect your scenario code to hit.

similarly you can write compact tests for the other 2 scenarios as well..

and then finally for the last scenario, you have the proper unit test.
the only thing i would do is extract out some private helper methods to make the actual unit test pretty crisp and readable as follows:

```
   [TestMethod]
   public void IsOrderShippable_OrderIsShippable_ShouldReturnTrue()
   {
      // you can parametrize this helper method as needed
      var inventoryService = GetMockInventoryServiceWithItemsNotOnHold();

      // You can parametrize this helper method with credit line, etc.
      var customerService = GetMockCustomerService(1000m);

      // parametrize this method with number of items and total price etc.
      Order order = GetTestOrderWithItems();

      OrderManager orderManager = new OrderManager(
         customerService: customerService.Object,
         inventoryService: inventoryService.Object);

      bool isShippable = orderManager.IsOrderShippable(order);

      Assert.IsTrue(isShippable);
   }
```

As you can see, by using helper methods, you made the test smaller and crisper, but we do lose some readability in terms of what parameters are being setup.

However, i tend to be very explicit about helper method names and parameter names, so that by reading the method name and parameters, a reader is clear about what sort of data is being arranged.

Most of the times, the happy path scenarios end up requiring the maximum setup code, since they need all the mocks setup properly with all correlated items, quantity, prices etc. In those cases, i prefer to sometimes put all the setup code on the TestSetup method.. so that it is by default available to every test method.

The upside, is that the tests get a good mock value out of the box.. (your happy path unit test can literally be just 2 lines, since you can keep a well-valid Order ready in the TestSetup method)

The downside is that the happy path scenario is typically one unit test.. but putting that stuff in the testSetup will run it for every unit test, even though they would never need it.

Option #2

Here is another way..

you could breakdown your IsOrderShippable method into 4 private methods that each exercise the 4 scenarios. You can make these private methods internal and then have your unit tests, work on those methods (internalsvisibleto etc.).. it is still a bit clunky, since you are making private methods internal, and also you still need to unit test your public method, which brings us kinda back to the original problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've had difficulty finding examples like yours of tests that require more than a few lines of code.